# How to open a URL using browser after scanning QR code in C#?

Tags: c#, url, qr-code

I have created a QR code. I want to open my site after scanning the QR code, but it always only shows text. How can I open a website using a browser after scanning my QR code in C#?

Here is my qrcode.aspx.cs:

```
using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url= "http://mysite/login.aspx";
            QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
            encoder.QRCodeScale = 10;
            System.Drawing.Image logo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/img/logo.gif"));

            Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(url);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            int left = (img.Width - logo.Width) / 2;
            int top = (img.Height - logo.Height) / 2;
            g.DrawImage(logo, new Point(left, top));
            img.Save(Server.MapPath("/qrcode/" + url+ ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "/qrcode/" + url+ ".jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Process.Start(url);`?

Comment: So your website generates your WR code, then you get your phone out, point it at the screen and.. it doesn't open the url?

Comment: ps; I'm not sure I would bother to save the image file to the server hard disk etc, just base64 encode it and set it as the contents of the img src= attribute so that it is sent inline with the rest of the page - complete waste of resources to save it to the disk then make a url that points to it, and force the client to make another request for it